# Winamp with gen_scripting in Jscript

Tags: plugins, jscript, winamp

Using the gen_scripting plugin for Winamp you must instantiate the object. In VBS this is

```
Set winamp = CreateObject("gen_scripting.WinAmp")
```

However, I'm pretty sure that the same plug-in can be used to script Winamp using Jscript (or possibly even Javascript - a better choice for me). So, I've tried

```
var winamp = Object.create("gen_scripting.WinAmp");
x = winamp.GetVersion();
alert(x);
winamp.ButtonPlay;
```

Only that doesn't work. Any help to get me started would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JScript analog of VBScript `CreateObject()` is [`new ActiveXObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sw4ddf8%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

Also, `alert` is a browser-specific function; in Windows shell scripts you should use [`WScript.Echo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8f603s7%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

```
var winamp = new ActiveXObject("gen_scripting.WinAmp");
var x = winamp.GetVersion();
WScript.Echo(x);
winamp.ButtonPlay();
```

Comment: Thank you. That works fine (just as long as you remember to run Winamp first) :)